# Can you use some kind of wildcard character in URL redirects in Joomla's Redirect component?

Tags: redirect, joomla

I need to redirect a bunch of URLs from one path to another. Is there a way I can do a bulk URL redirect using some kind of wildcard character? I'm using Joomla's Redirect component

Old URL path: `/about/news/entry/article_title`

New URL path: `/news/entry/article_title`

I tried using an asterisk by redirecting `/about/news/entry/*` to `/news/entry/*`, but it didn't work. There are 230 news articles and new ones are being published every week. I'm hoping I can find a catch-all solution.

I'd like to avoid using htaccess since my version of Joomla says modifying htaccess might break the site. Which, is awesome.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jumbo is a member of JSE.  When Joomla users post their Joomla questions or answers outside of JSE, that dedicated community misses an opportunity to grow.  Please help us to grow JSE.

Comment: @mickmackusa I agree. Next time onwards I will request all such questions to be posted at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rochelle  since all posters on this page are also members of JSE, if you would like to have this page migrated to JSE, I can facilitate this action.  Just leave a comment that you authorize this migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Joomla redirect component for bulk URL redirect. You can use a custom system plugin for the same. Refer to this documentation to learn how you can create custom Joomla plugins - https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

Here are the example codes of the plugin -

**customredirect.php**

```
<?php

defined ('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgSystemCustomRedirect extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Application object.
     *
     * @var    JApplicationCms
     */
    protected $app;
    
    /**
     * Match and redirect to new urls
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onAfterRoute()
    {
        $doc = $this->app->getDocument();
        
        if (!$this->app->isClient('site') || $doc->getType() !== 'html')
        {
            return;
        }
        
        $url     = JUri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme', 'host', 'port', 'path', 'query', 'fragment'));
        $find    = JUri::base() . 'about/news/entry/';
        $replace = JUri::base() . 'news/entry/';
        
        if (strpos($url, $find) === 0 && strlen($url) > strlen($find))
        {
            $newUrl = str_replace($find, $replace, $url);
            
            $this->app->redirect($newUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

**customredirect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.5" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
    <name>System - Custom Redirect</name>
    <author>Jumbo</author>
    <creationDate>May 2021</creationDate>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="customredirect">customredirect.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

If you have any further queries related to Joomla, please post here - https://joomla.stackexchange.com/